# android related spinner

Tags: android

How to perform android related spinner?

I have done it like this:

private Spinner ddlCountry, ddlCategory;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pnplandingpage);

        ddlCountry = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ddlCountry);
        ddlCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ddlCategory);

        // BindCountry(ddlCountry);

        // ddlCountry
        // .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnCountryItemSelectedListener());

        // ddlCategory
        // .setOnItemSelectedListener(new
        // OnCategoryItemSelectedListener());

        // ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter
        // .createFromResource(this, R.array.Country_array,
        // android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // ddlCountry.setAdapter(adapter);

        ddlCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View pview,
                    int pos, long id) {

                final String[] array = new String[] { "Category",
                        "5 Miles", "10 Miles", "15 Miles", "20 Miles",
                        "25 Miles", };

                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    list.add(array[i]);
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        PNPLandingPage.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter
                        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                ddlCategory.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                Toast.makeText(
                        parent.getContext(),
                        "The Country is "
                                + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
                // Do nothing.
                ddlCategory.setAdapter(null);

            }
        });

        // BindCategory(ddlCategory);

        // ddlCategory
        // .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnCategoryItemSelectedListener());

        ddlCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View pview,
                    int pos, long id) {

                final String[] array = new String[] { "Country",
                        "Country1", "Country2", "Country3", "Country4",
                        "Country5", };


                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    list.add(array[i]);
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        PNPLandingPage.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter
                        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                ddlCountry.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                // ddlCategory
                // .setOnItemSelectedListener(new
                // OnCategoryItemSelectedListener());

                Toast.makeText(
                        parent.getContext(),
                        "The Category is "
                                + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
                // Do nothing.
                ddlCountry.setAdapter(null);

            }
        });

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "EXCEPTION :" + ex, 1000);
    }
}
```

But the Toast gets fired every time, i.e the onItemSelected gets repeated. what am i doing mistake..

Comment: which toast get displayed ???

Comment: first the parent toast gets displayed then the category , this continues as a loop..

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is ,

when you set setOnItemSelectedListener() to any spinner so the first item of list (or array you assigned to it) by default get selected so it fires the onItemSelected() selected.

And in your case your both spinners are firing onItemSelected() method.So they are in a kind of infinite loop.

Edited Answer

```
final String[] array = new String[]
        { "Country", "Country1", "Country2", "Country3", "Country4", "Country5", };

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            list.add(array[i]);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TwoSpinners.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ddlCountry.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        ddlCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View pview, int pos, long id)
            {
                if (!parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Country"))
                {
                    final String[] array = new String[]
                    { "Category", "5 Miles", "10 Miles", "15 Miles", "20 Miles", "25 Miles", };

                    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                    {
                        list.add(array[i]);
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TwoSpinners.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    ddlCategory.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The Country is " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent)
            {
                // Do nothing.
                ddlCategory.setAdapter(null);

            }
        });

        // BindCategory(ddlCategory);

        // ddlCategory
        // .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnCategoryItemSelectedListener());

        ddlCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View pview, int pos, long id)
            {

                if (!parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Category"))
                {

                    final String[] array = new String[]
                    { "Country", "Country1", "Country2", "Country3", "Country4", "Country5", };

                    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                    {
                        list.add(array[i]);
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TwoSpinners.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    ddlCountry.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                    // ddlCategory
                    // .setOnItemSelectedListener(new
                    // OnCategoryItemSelectedListener());

                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The Category is " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent)
            {
                // Do nothing.
                ddlCountry.setAdapter(null);

            }
        });
```

Comment: yes you are correct , It creates a infinite loop. The selected item also gets changed due to this loop.  I'm trying like a cascasding dropdown when i change the parent the child must be loaded according to that and when i select the child parent will have to change how can i handle it.. how can i avoid this?

Comment: How to avoid onItemSelected fuction call during the spinner load?

Comment: All the time you are loading the same data to spinners so what is the need of making list on basis of other spinner's selection.

Comment: Ya i tried those steps also also it doesnt work only the first Country selected categories are displayed.. The selected item also gets changed to the initial value

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same infite loop. Calling in `onItemSelected()`, `setContentView()` and my class method `setupSpinner()`, and in this method i do `mspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)`, which calls `onItemSelected()` again...

Fixed with my handler: `handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 500)` with a delay of 500ms. The Runnable containts only: `mspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)`